# Неполный тип

Tags: c++

Есть код вида

```
struct A
{
    ...
    struct B
    {
        A a; //ошибка
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

Компилятор ругается на то, что A имеет неполный тип. Выносить `B` из `A` и захламлять пространство имён не хочу. Выделять `A` в куче в конструкторе `B` тоже не хочется, объект очень маленький, часто создаётся и живёт недолго.

Я попробовал создать массив байтов, в который поместится `A` и при каждом использовании преобразовывать его к A. Но компилятор в релизе выдаёт тысячи предупреждений `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]`. Вроде решается выключение оптимизации, но так как этот заголовочный файл включают все без исключения cpp-файлы проекта, то придётся отключать эту оптимизацию у всего проекта из-за такой мелкой структурки. На stackoverflow я вычитал, что это предупреждение игнорировать нельзя, так как будет undefined behaviour, и могут в самый неожиданный момент возникнуть очень странные глюки.

Есть ли какой-то способ обойти ошибки и предупреждения, не вынося структуру B изнутри A и не трогая кучу?

Эх, как же мне надоело бороться с этими крестопроблемами... Перешёл бы на D, там такого нет, но к сожалению не могу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конкретно эту "крестопроблему" можно решить так:

```
struct A
{
    struct B;
};

struct A::B
{
    A a;
};
```

Comment: А есть ли все таки способ осведомить структуру B о родительском типе A без выноса?

Comment: @0xFFh

- В таких вопросах крайне важна терминология. Что значит "осведомить"? На момент определения `B` (в авторском варианте) `A` — это [incomplete type,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349822/incomplete-type-in-class) поскольку `B` определяется inline внутри объявления `A`. Поэтому невозможность "осведомления" прямо следует из стандарта.

- Мой вариант полностью эквивалентен авторскому, но `B` объявляется внутри `A` (то есть inline), а определяется уже за пределами `A` в тот момент, когда `A` уже не является incomplete type.

Comment: О как раз только что сам до этого додумался. Думал, что так сделать нельзя, попробовал и получилось.